# Delphi: How to prevent MSXML from encoding in UTF-8 an already encoded XML

Tags: delphi

I was using a stringlist to make a simple xml where I inserted the nodes via Add to make a UTF8 encoded xml

eg.

```
    myXML.Add('<myNode>'+UTF8Encode('υτφ8στρινγ')+'</myNode>');
```

However I wanted to switch to IXMLDocument form more clean code and versatility

I am making a simple xml in Delphi

```
procedure myxml;
var
  xmlDoc : IXMLDocument;
  xNode : IXMLNode;
begin
  xmlDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    xmlDoc.Active := TRUE;
    xmlDoc.Version := '1.0';
    xmlDoc.Encoding := 'utf-8';
    xNode := xmlDoc.AddChild('myNode');
    xNode.Text := UTF8Encode('υτφ8στρινγ'); //greek chars
    xmlDoc.XML.SaveToFile('test.xml');  
  finally
    FreeAndNil(xmlDoc);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that the output XML is encoded in UTF-8 twice. I believe the problem has to do with MSXML which encodes (via MSXML.save()) in UTF-8 by default.

So what I need is to somehow have MSXML not encode the XML but have the header

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Ok sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you should not be performing any UTF-8 encoding. Pass strings to the XML library, and let it do the encoding. So, replace

```
xNode.Text := UTF8Encode('υτφ8στρινγ');
```

with

```
xNode.Text := 'υτφ8στρινγ';
```

You must remove that call to `FreeAndNil`. You are passing an interface reference and `FreeAndNil` is for object instance references. Simply remove it and let the interface reference counting code do its work.

Comment: Well I figured that this would be one solution, however, I put the UTF8Encode for display reasons. In the production code this is an ANSI string with UTF-8 chars. eg in the DB the string is saved as `Ο…Ο„Ο†8ΟƒΟ„ΟΞΉΞ½Ξ` (Don't ask why :D). Would converting the utf8 string to unicode be a solution?

Comment: You should convert the UTF8 encoded string to UTF-16. Exactly how you do that depends on what version of Delphi you have. You ought to tell us that. It's also somewhat unfair to ask one question, and then tell us that you meant to ask a different question. If you want to ask a question about the real situation, make sure that the question reflects that. If you are working with AnsiString variables, show us them in the question. I answered the question that you asked. How can we be expected to answer a question that you did not ask?

Comment: You don't have to accept my answer by the way. Do please feel free to edit the question to ask about your actual scenario. I can see that you are new here and I'm very happy to cut you a little slack to allow for that. I'm quite sure we can work it all out for you.

Comment: XML nodes operate on UTF-16 encoded strings, even in pre-Unicode versions of Delphi. That is why you cannot pass UTF-8 strings as-is. In D2009+, at least, you should use `UTF8String` and get rid of `UTF8Encode()`, at least. If you pass a `UTF8String` to a `UnicodeString`, the RTL automatically converts the UTF-8 data to UTF-16 for you.